# Pass SIGINT while pressing ctrl+c on using debugger in vscode

Tags: gdb, visual-studio-code

I know we could use the handle signal command in gdb to make it pass the SIGINT signal to the program. Is there a way to do the same while using the debugger in vs code?

Answer (score 5):

Open another terminal.

```
ps -eaf |grep <Proc-Name>   //  find the PID

kill -s SIGINT PID_OF_PROCESS
```

---

Get back to VS Code
Now you can see and use the stacktrace etc.

Comment: This works great combining with -exec handle SIGINT nostop pass in the Debug Console. If I hit CTRL+C, it does not stop at my breakpoint even with -exec handle SIGINT nostop pass set.

Answer (score 4):

In the Debug Console of vs code write:

-exec handle SIGINT pass
-exec handle SIGINT nostop

Comment: Does this not work anymore? I'm getting "identifier "exec" is undefined"

Comment: Just use the Debug Console instead of the Terminal window.

Comment: This requires "stopAtEntry": true in lauch.json and run -exec handle SIGINT nostop while it is stopped at the entry. If "stopAtEntry" is set to false, "Unable to perform this action because the process is running".

Comment: Even with `stopAtEntry` set to `true` it just shuts down and the SIGINT handler in my program is ignored. :/

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, VScode 1.87.1